# Implementing a custom table section header via Storyboard and new Xib

Tags: ios

Here is what I have done:

I created a custom `xib` file that has a small UIView used for a custom table section header.
I classed the custom `xib` file.

I want to add this to a tableView as the header. I have looked at a few resources, but they seem to be either outdated or missing information.

Looking in the documentation, I see a reference to adding a custom header with the following instructions:

> To make the table view aware of your header or footer view, you need to register it. You do this using the registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: or registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: method of UITableView.

When I added a tableView to my storyboard view, it was easy to assign it a reuse identifier within XCode. I was even able to create a custom cell `xib` file and it also had a spot for a reuse identifier within XCode.

When I created the custom UIView for the section header, it did not have an entry for reuse identifier. Without this, I have no idea how to use `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier`.

More information:
I have a storyboard scene that has a `tableView` inside. The `tableView` is of a custom class that is linked and the `tableView` object has an outlet in the parent view's `ViewController` file.

The parent `ViewController` is both the `UITableViewDataSourceDelegate` and `UITableViewDelegate`. Again, I was able to implement the custom cells with no issue. I can't even modify the header in any way besides the title.

I tried calling the method `[[self tableHeaderView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];` from the custom `tableView` class and nothing happens. I tried using this method in the parent `ViewController` class by using the outlet name like so:
`[[self.tableOutlet tableHeaderView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: (Can't change background to transparent)

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    HeaderView *headerView = [self.TableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"tableHeader"];

    // Set Background color
    [[headerView contentView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    // Set Text
    headerView.headerLabel.text = [self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:section];

    return headerView;
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need to set the identifier in the xib -- you just need to use the same identifier when you register, and when you dequeue the header view. In the viewDidLoad method, I registered the view like this:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Header1" bundle:nil] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:@"header1"];
```

Then, in the delegate methods:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *headerView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"header1"];
    return headerView;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 100;
}
```

Comment: I implemented this and it seems to work, but the background for the header is still the default style. I am able to use the label I placed in my custom `xib` file to change the text of the header. I have the label as an outlet in the header's class files (CustomHeader.h, CustomHeader.m).

Comment: @orbv, you have to use headerView.contentView.backgroundColor = ... to change the background color.

Comment: I tried inserting that and it still stays the same. Again, setting the custom label text works great. I posted the code snippet in an edit.

Comment: @orbv, that's because the default header view also has a backgroundView property with that look, so you can see through to it if your color is clear. If you add, headerView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:headerView.frame]; you will put in a new clear view.

Comment: So there are 2 headers: a table header and a section header? Adding that line of code worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @orbv, yes, there is a separate table header that scrolls up with the table view. It doesn't stick to the top like the section headers.

Answer (score 0):

On the problem with background color (Unless you want transparent):

You can create an `UIView` which occupies the whole view then change the background color of that.

If you don't want others to know what's happening, you can overwrite the backgroundColor property:

```
//interface
@property (copy, nonatomic) UIColor *backgroundColor;


//implementation
@dynamic backgroundColor;

- (void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor {
    //self.viewBackground is the created view
    [self.viewBackground setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
}

- (UIColor *)backgroundColor {
    return self.viewBackground.backgroundColor;
}
```